# OverflowError: user id is too big

Tags: python, linux, macos

Runtime environment:

Mac OS X 10.8.3 Intel 64bit

Python 2.7.3

**How to solve the setuid nobody length issue?**

bash

```
$ id nobody
uid=4294967294(nobody) gid=4294967294(nobody) groups=4294967294(nobody),12(everyone),61(localaccounts)

$ cat /etc/password
nobody:*:-2:-2:Unprivileged User:/var/empty:/usr/bin/false
```

python

```
>>> import pwd
>>> import os
>>> uid = pwd.getpwnam('nobody')
>>> uid
pwd.struct_passwd(pw_name='nobody', pw_passwd='*', pw_uid=4294967294, pw_gid=4294967294, pw_gecos='Unprivileged User', pw_dir='/var/empty', pw_shell='/usr/bin/false')
>>> uid = pwd.getpwnam('nobody')[2]
>>> uid
4294967294
>>> os.setuid(uid)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OverflowError: user id too big
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem is fixed in Python 2.7.4, 3.2.4, and 3.3.1 (see http://bugs.python.org/issue4591).